# Python 3.8 class variable not persistent

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

A class variable for a Python class does not appear to persist between packages.

I have a class "HookRegistry" that is supposed to dynamically record the functions that are annotated with the @regiser_hook method. IT does so successfully, but when I go again to find out the list of hooks registered, the list variable holding them appears to be reinitialized.

```py
class HookRegistry(object):
    hooks = []

    def register_hook(f):
        HookRegistry.hooks.append(f)
        print("Registrering hook. There are now {} hooks registered.".format(len(HookRegistry.hooks)))
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap

    def execute_hooks(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in HookRegistry.hooks:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Full source code can be found at https://github.com/conallprendergast/python_hook_registry_example/tree/not_working

I am running python 3.8 on arch linux

Comment: How do you determine it has been reinitialized? In your example code, the actual hook execution will always die with a `KeyError` (because it tries to read a key from `kwargs` which wasn't passed). Also note: Both of your functions should be decorated with `@staticmethod` (or the pointless class wrapping should be removed, since these are effectively global functions) to make it clear they don't use instance data at all.

Comment: You don't need the wrapper; just return `f`. The point of `register_hook` isn't to add functionality to the decorated function, but merely to update a list.

Comment: @chepner: Especially given they neglect to `return` the value from `f`, so the wrapping would break any function with non-`None` return values.

Comment: A `KeyError` only results if a keyword argument `f` doesn't expect is passed.

Comment: @chepner: I'm referring to their actual example code, where the `f` functions all accept `**kwargs`, but then assume `kwargs` contains the key `"day"`.

Comment: Ah, stuff that's not in the question. I'm ignoring that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am not sure if it is reinitialised or not, that was just my guess. Why does the list of hooks become empty when I try to access it from the main method?

Comment: Also I am open to suggestions of other ways to do this "function register" application

Comment: @user98651: The question is whether and how you're sure it was ever *not* empty. How do you know it's empty when you access it from `main`? How do you know anything was *ever* added to it?

Comment: Does not look like the methods are defined with a @staticmethod decorator, yet they are static methods based on their signature.

Comment: @user98651 I print out the length of the list of hooks every time I add a hook. Thats how I know it is actually populating my list of hooks. Anyhow, I have figured out the issue and will post the answer below. If any of ye know _why_ this fixes it, do let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed by changing my code in my "hook" do_something* files. The import of

```
from hookregistry import HookRegistry
```

needs to be changed to

```
from .hookregistry import HookRegistry
```

Answer (score -1):

This is no working because module `do_something*` doesn't executed.(we easy can check this: just add incorrect code to `do_something.py`

This can be fixed, add this code to `hooks/__init__.py`

```
from .do_something import *
from .do_something_else import *
```

Comment: These modules are imported from the __init__.py __all__ declaration. Adding syntactically incorrect code to the do_something giles does in fact break the code